# How to custom the TextArea line background color

Tags: qt, qml, textarea

I want to compare two TextArea's text ,and change the different text's line background color,but i don't know how can have tow background color in one TextArea. Maybe should custom to get it,what should i do?
or import .js to get it ? what should i do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing a single strings color within a QTextEdit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24287111/changing-a-single-strings-color-within-a-qtextedit) Instead of changing the font color, you can set it to background-color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a more advance solution, you can manipulate `TextArea` content with https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html `QTextDocument`. Original text document is available via this property https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textedit.html#textDocument-prop . From this point, you can assign your own syntax highlighting. But it requires research from your side.

From the other side, you can check this example https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-codeeditor-example.html and using this class https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsyntaxhighlighter.html you can assign the existing `QTextDocument` to `QSyntaxHighlighter`. The same, I guess, can be used for QML `TextArea` element.

Since `TextArea` has `textDocument` property it should be possible re-implement it for QtQuick Constrols.

To be honest I've never dealt with such a task, but this example looks pretty useful for such cases. Probably you should stick with rich text format option suggested in comments if you don't need advanced features (like real-time content changes).